# Add iCloud account to Outlook calenders on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, ms-office

I want to add my iCloud account to my outlook calendar on my iPhone 13 (software version 15.2). Note: My iCloud account is not registered via an @icloud.com mail address.
I created an app-specific password for outlook but it still isn't working. Outlook still says that it needs an app-specific password even though I already created one.

Comment: You subscribed to the calendar from outlook.com?

Comment: Sorry @MarcWilson, I don't quite understand your question. I want to add my calendars registered under my iCloud account to the outlook calendar in the outlook app on my iPhone.